# How to copy from NSMutableArray to NSMutableString?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

Im trying to add some strings into NSMutableArray,than want to copy element 0(zero)
from NSMutableArray to NSMutableString

```
[MS appendString:str]
```

this line raises error.

what is the problem ?
a MutableArray element cannot be assigned to NSString ?
(thanks for any responses)

error output is :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c82440'

here is my code :

```
NSMutableArray *A=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableString *MS=[NSMutableString stringWithString:@"first"];

for (int i=0; i<=15;i+=2) {
    [A addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]];
}

NSString *str;

for (int x=0; x<[A count]; x++) {
    str=[A objectAtIndex:0];
    [MS appendString:str];//ERROR HERE
}

[A release];
```

Answer (score 2):

You are adding `NSNumber`s to the array and not strings n the folioing line:

```
[A addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]]; // here you are adding numbers
```

So when you read them from the array later, they are **still** numbers and you have to create strings from them:

```
NSString *str;
NSNumber *number;

for (int x=0; x<[A count]; x++) {
    number = [A objectAtIndex:0]; // You should probably replace 0 by x here.
    str = [number stringValue]; // transform number into a string
    [MS appendString:str];
}

[A release];
```

But if you want the array to store strings and not numbers, then replace the first loop instead with the following:

```
for (int i=0; i<=15;i+=2) {
    [A addObject:[[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i] stringValue]];
}
```

Or

```
for (int i=0; i<=15;i+=2) {
    [A addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i]];
}
```